# Excel VBA delete all files in selection of folders

Tags: excel, file, directory

I'm looking to compile a list of all Excel file within a set of folders.  Those files have been compiled using a different process we have internally, I want to delete all of those files from the specified folders.

I can only imagine that this would be some kind of LOOP function but I'm not certain how to even start this.  I know the set of folders that I'm looking for, but that's where it stops.

Forgive my ignorance but I'm nearly a complete novice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). The use of the word compiled is going to cause confusion here because it appears that you are using the non-programmer meaning of the word.

Comment: If those folders only contain target files, then delete the folder and replace with a new empty one - less checking involved...

Answer (score 0):

using windows file viewer, navigate to the top level folder and do a search for *.xls, or *.xlsx, or if the folders only contain excel files you can do * . * (without the spaces) . This will list all files and you can select what you want and delete them

Comment: It isn't really a rookie question. I struggled with this at one point and it seems like it's a problem that you would need to program something for and using Windows search isn't really the first thing that comes to mind for something like this.

Comment: Maybe include an example command in your answer: `dir /B /S directory/*.xsl* > file_list.txt`? where `/B` is bare listing, and `/S/` is recursive subdirectories.

Comment: I didn't say to use command prompt. I said windows file viewer. Aka the thing you use to look at files in windows. There aren't any fancy commands you have to enter. You literally type in * . * in the search bar when you're at the top level folder and it shows you every file in every folder and subfolder. OP said he wanted to delete a bunch of files. This is the quickest way to do it.